# Update table with average calculation from itself using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I do have the following test table. The table contains trading securities.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test

CREATE TABLE "test" (SecurityID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                     Ticker TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                     Type TEXT,
                     Underlying TEXT,
                     TER NUMERIC)

INSERT INTO test (Ticker, Type, Underlying, TER)
VALUES ('Ticker1', 'ETF', 'U1', 0.0005),
       ('Ticker2', 'ETF', 'U2', 0.0010),
       ('Ticker3', 'ETF', 'U1', 0.0025),
       ('Ticker4', 'ETF', 'U1', 0.0015),
       ('Ticker5', 'ETF', 'U3', 0.0055),
       ('Ticker6', 'ETF', 'U3', 0.0010),
       ('Ticker7', 'Index', NULL, NULL),
       ('Ticker8', 'ETF', 'U4', 0.002),
       ('Ticker9', 'Index', NULL, NULL),
       ('U1', 'Index', NULL, NULL),
       ('U3', 'Index', NULL, NULL),
       ('U4', 'Index', NULL, NULL)
```

Now, I need to specify the `TER` column for securities of type `Index`. Every row with type `ETF` has the `TER` field filled. They also have the field `Underlying` filled. `Underlying` may correspond to other rows in the table, namely those rows that have the same value in the `Ticker` field.

I would like to compute the average of `TER`, grouped by `Underlying` and apply these values to the respective rows where `Underlying` of an ETF corresponds to the respective `Ticker` field.

Here's my solution so far. However, this is not fully working. It only updates the TER for row 10 (`Ticker` 'U1') with the correct value of 0.0015 ((0.005 + 0.0025 + 0.0015)/3).
For U3, I expect a TER value of 0.0033 ((0.0055 + 0.0010)/2).
For U4, I expect a TER value of 0.002.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
AS
SELECT Underlying, round(AVG(TER), 4) as TER FROM test
WHERE Type='ETF'
GROUP BY Underlying

-- Update TERs of all rows with type 'Index' using the average TER from all rows with
-- type 'ETF', grouped by Underlying.
UPDATE test
SET TER = (SELECT TER FROM tmp)
WHERE Ticker = (SELECT Underlying FROM tmp)
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: ``TER``s in the last three rows should be updated as follows: 0.0015, 0.0033, 0.002

Comment: Yes, I calculated that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Test
SET TER = COALESCE(
  (SELECT ROUND(AVG(t.TER), 4) FROM Test t WHERE t.Type = 'ETF' AND t.Underlying = Test.Ticker), 
  TER
)
WHERE Ticker IN (SELECT DISTINCT Underlying FROM Test)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=748230c2d204c6ff8117593eb08279c4).

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you could also use UPDATE...FROM syntax:

```
UPDATE Test AS t
SET TER = g.TER
FROM (
  SELECT Underlying, ROUND(AVG(TER), 4) as TER FROM test
  WHERE Type='ETF'
  GROUP BY Underlying  
) AS g  
WHERE t.Ticker = g.Underlying;
```

See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7943c/2).

Results (for your sample data):

```
 SecurityID | Ticker  | Type  | Underlying |    TER
 ---------: | :------ | :---- | :--------- | -----:
          1 | Ticker1 | ETF   | U1         | 0.0005
          2 | Ticker2 | ETF   | U2         |  0.001
          3 | Ticker3 | ETF   | U1         | 0.0025
          4 | Ticker4 | ETF   | U1         | 0.0015
          5 | Ticker5 | ETF   | U3         | 0.0055
          6 | Ticker6 | ETF   | U3         |  0.001
          7 | Ticker7 | Index | null       |   null
          8 | Ticker8 | ETF   | U4         |  0.002
          9 | Ticker9 | Index | null       |   null
         10 | U1      | Index | null       | 0.0015
         11 | U3      | Index | null       | 0.0033
         12 | U4      | Index | null       |  0.002
```

Comment: That's definitely the expected result. Can you please take a look at your second solution? It's not working...Some SQL syntax issue.

Comment: @Andi The 2nd solution works only in SQLite 3.33.0+

Comment: OK, just wondering, because your link at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7943c/2 is not working.

Comment: @Andi it's working for me, I just tested it. This is the only fiddle online that has SQLite 3.33.0

Comment: That's weird. I do get the following error: ``could not prepare statement (1 near "FROM": syntax error)``

Comment: @Andi It is weird, execute `SELECT sqlite_version()` For me, it returns 3.33.0

Comment: @Andi I figured it out. http://sqlfiddle.com's SQLite (WebSQL) which uses version 3.33.0 of SQLite does not work on all browsers. I'm using Opera and it works. In Firefox 84.0 it does not work.